# Getting this ERROR processing skip func of , while deploying contract

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Im currently watching fcc solidity course and im trying to deploy a smart contract but it throws this error idk no what to do

`ERROR processing skip func of /home/deepak/blockchain-dev/hardhat-raffle/deploy/00-deploy-mock.js:`

00-deploy-mock.js:

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

const BASE_FEE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25") //0.25link is cost to get Random no
const GAS_PRICE_LINK = 1e9 // calculated value based on the gas price of the chain
const args = [BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK]
module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
   const { deploy, log } = deployments
   const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
   const chainId = network.config.chainId

   if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
      log("Local Network detected! Deploying.......")
      await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", {
         from: deployer,
         args: args,
         log: true,
         waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
      })
      log("Mocks Deployed!")
      log("-------------------------------------------------")
   }
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer version of Ethers seems to be unstable ethers 6.0.2... To solve this error downgrade your ethers version to 5.7.2 by going to your package.json

"ethers": "5.7.2"

now on your cli use npm install ethers@5.7.2 or yarn add ethers@5.7.2 depending on your package manager and that should solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

i uninstalled

`@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle`

and installed `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers` and it worked finally